# CSS Not Loading for Include PHP File

Tags: php, css

I cannot figure out how to apply styles to a page I am including as a template. I have the following directory structure:

```
app
│   index.php
│   styles.css   
│
└───include
│   │   mainmenu.php
```

My INDEX file looks like this

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learn Algorithm Tracing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"</link>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include 'includes/menu.php';
?>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
```

The CSS works fine in this page and loads OK. However I'm having trouble understanding how to get CSS styles to apply to my mainmenu.php file. At the moment it looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<p class="menuitem">HOME</p>
<p class="menuitem">I KNOW</p>
<p class="menuitem">I WANT</p>
<p class="menuitem">I GOT</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I added ..\ as the styles for this are stored in the main CSS file which is in the parent directory. However, it doesn't apply the menuitem style here. I've tried every combination I can think of but how do I go about it? How do I apply the styles in the main stylesheet to my mainmenu.php page when it's been included in index.php

EDIT:

Interestingly, when I include one of the styles already used in the index page it works fine, but for some reason it doesn't like the menuitem style. Here is the CSS

```
body{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
}

.maintext {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}
.entryprompt{
    width: 50px;
}
.menuitem{
    font-family: "Arial Narrow", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16pt;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the CSS in a folder? Or how comes ur using "\..\styles.css"

Comment: Try changing it to this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css"/>`

Comment: I think the issue may have lay somewhere else. I have updated by question

Comment: why is there include/mainmenu.php (tree) and includes/menu.php (not in the tree, but in index.php) ?

Answer (score 2):

try using `../styles.css` instead of `\..\styles.css` and close the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work, and PHPStorm doesn't seem to like that I closed the tag

Answer (score 2):

You are using bad slash in html `link` tag change `\` to this `/` so CSS import will look like this.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css"/>`

**Update:**

When you include some file then you should use path from the file you are including it to. Try this.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>`